# Undefined Reference to Global Variable in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables

The header:

```css
#ifndef DECLARATIONS_H_
#define DECLARATIONS_H_

#endif /*DECLARATIONS_H_*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

extern int pointer;
```

Main cpp:

```css
#include "Declarations.h"
int main() {

    string input = "something something";
    int pointer = input.length();
}
```

And then when I use it in another .cpp that includes the header at the very top and uses "pointer", it gives an undefined reference pointer.

I don't think it is a linking problem either because when I use functions from the C libraries that I included in the header file in the cpp files it works.

Comment: _"I don't think it is a linking problem ..."_ Wrong. It's definitly a linker problem, you must have a definition for that variable in one of your translation units: `int pointer;`. The definition in `main()` shadows the declaration from the `extern` statement.

Comment: If it is a linker problem, how do I fix it?

Comment: I mentioned what you need to do: Provide a definition for that variable.

Comment: But my int pointer = input.length() is a definition of the variable, is it not? What do you mean it "shadows" the declaration?

Comment: As also mentioned it's not the definition of the variable from the `extern` statement, but a local variable inside the `main()` function.